# Python peewee mysql inner join alias difficulty

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

With PHP and standard MySQL, I had a query like this:

```
#SELECT AGCs.name AS agcname, npa, nxx, COUNT( npa ) AS ooscount
#          FROM MTAs
#          INNER JOIN AGCs ON AGCs.id = MTAs.agcid
#          WHERE agcid = agcid
#          GROUP BY npa, nxx
#          ORDER BY  `ooscount` DESC
```

This worked great and was tested via phpMyadmin and later in my front end.

Now, I'm refactoring a bunch of my code to optimize, etc and having trouble getting this query to work in Python/Peewee.

```
cquery = Agcs.select(Agcs.name.alias('agcname'), Mtas.npa.alias('npa'), Mtas.nxx.alias('nxx'), fn.COUNT(Mtas.npa).alias('npaooscount')).join(Mtas, JOIN.INNER, on=(Agcs.id == Mtas.agcid)).where(Mtas.agcid == agcid).group_by(Mtas.npa, Mtas.nxx).order_by(Mtas.ooscount)
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why it doesn't like the order by clause.

```
  File "testing_join.py", line 69, in <module>
    cquery = Agcs.select(Agcs.name.alias('agcname'), Mtas.npa.alias('npa'), Mtas.nxx.alias('nxx'), fn.COUNT(Mtas.npa).alias('npaooscount')).join(Mtas, JOIN.INNER, on=(Agcs.id == Mtas.agcid)).switch(Mtas).where(Mtas.agcid == agcid).group_by(Mtas.npa, Mtas.nxx).order_by(npaooscount)
NameError: name 'npaooscount' is not defined
```

While it's true that Mtas.ooscount doesn't exist, I'm setting that as a alias earlier in the query.

Here are my models if you need to see structure

```
class Agcs(BaseModel):
    alert = IntegerField()
    diff = CharField()
    diff_ooscount = CharField()
    name = CharField()
    ooscount = IntegerField()
    runtime = CharField()
    updated = DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'AGCs'

class Mtas(BaseModel):
    ad = CharField()
    agcid = IntegerField()
    as_ = CharField(column_name='as')
    dn = CharField()
    fqdn = CharField()
    npa = CharField()
    nxx = CharField()
    ps = CharField()
    timestamp = DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'MTAs'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried Mtas.npa.npaooscount which gave a different error.

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Mtas.npa.npaooscount'

Comment: Why are you doing all that alias-ing? Gross

Comment: Because I didn't know what I was doing, I'm not a "developer", so this isn't my background. I didn't know how to call things and figured it out, it's much cleaner now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I changed my query to a raw() rather than .select and had a typo.